# dfa subtract multiple of 3

Tags: automata, finite-automata, proof-techniques, induction

Define a function  ∈{0,1}→ℤ so: for everything w ∈{0,1}, diff w = # of 1's in w- # of 0's in w.

Thus:
 =0;
 0=−1;
 0=−1;

Let  = {∈ {0,1} * |   = 3 for some  ∈ ℤ}.

the teacher only explained to me in class the functioning of the DFA multiple of 3
https://cdncontribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/dfadivision-1.jpg, with this dfa I must build the day that from the subtraction of the ones and zeros in w accept multiples of 3.

I did not have the next class, the teacher sent a pdf with a complicated explanation about Proving Correctness of DFA

How define a deterministic finite automaton M such that L (M) = L?

How proving correctness of DFA if diff w is a subtraction?

Comment: What exactly is your question? "Can you do my homework for me?" Yes, absolutely. "Will you do my homework form me?" No, not a chance. Defining M is really quite easy.

Comment: did you actually try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: with this dfa https://cdncontribute.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/dfadivision-1.jpg build this other   = 3 for some ; diff w = # of 1's in w- # of 0's in w.

Comment: only the operation of a single DFA